# ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.CatalogVersionProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jooq

Well, I'm trying to link Jooq in H2.

But throws the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jooq/util/CatalogVersionProvider at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048) at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018) at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784) at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>   at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jooq.util.CatalogVersionProvider  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

I'm testing only one entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Image {

@Id
private Integer idImage;
private String code;
private byte[] data;
private Double width;
private Double height;

// getters and setters
}
```

My JOOq configuration is on codegen.xml.

I'm using maven then my file is in src/main/resources:

[Maven Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In3WH.png)

And my GenerationTool configuration is like:

[GenerationTool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVqxH.png)

Comment: Your classpath seems to have errors, see the classpath tab in your second screenshot. Are you sure you're using the right jOOQ versions?

Comment: I just rename my project, but here is all right. I'll look the jOOQ version!

Comment: My pom is like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0r2JKv2WkmzMnNZXzdjUWlsZE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My mistake! Missed adding jooq-meta! thanks Lukas

Comment: No worries. You know, you can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow...